# Is there a correct way to uniformly quantize a color map?

Tags: visualization, sampling, colormap, scientific-computing

For general purpose visualization of continuous fields. For example, if you wanted to make a contour plot with 3 colors from a continuous color map, would you:

**A**) Use 3 equal-sized bins, each mapped to the color of the value at the center of the bin. This seems obvious but it shrinks the range of colors and never uses the two extremes so it doesn't look good.

**B**) Use 3 equal-sized bins, each mapped to a color within the range of the bin but uniformly spaced, including the ends.

**C**) Like **A** but extend the range of values beyond the range of colors by half a bin width at each end so they two end bins are effectively half the size of the others. Seems to be done here https://ai.googleblog.com/2019/08/turbo-improved-rainbow-colormap-for.html around the middle of the page.

**D**) ?

[image: 3 quantizations of a color map]

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Visual-Display-Quantitative-Information/dp/1930824130

Comment: Quick skim of that book doesn't seem to address this question. Can you identify a specific section or page?